# What is the output $y(t)$ when you have input $x(t) = \cos(2 \pi t) $ and frequency response response $h(t) = u(t) - u(t - 1/2)$?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

The output $y(t)$ is the convolution of input $x(t)$ with impulse response $h(t)$:
$$
 y(t) = h(t) * x(t)
$$

This is a linear, time invariant system.

What is the output $y(t)$ in real form when you have input $x(t) = \cos(2 \pi t)$,  $-\infty < t < \infty$ and frequency response response $h(t) = u(t) - u(t - 1/2)$? $u(t)$ is the unit step function.

I tried:
\begin{align*}
&\, \int_{-\infty}^\infty  (u(\tau) - u(\tau - 1/2)) *  \cos(2 \pi (t - \tau) ) \,\text{d} \tau \\
=&\, \int_{0}^{1/2}  \cos(2 \pi (t - \tau)) \,\text{d}\tau
= \left[ \frac{-\sin(2 \pi t - 2 \pi \tau)} {2\pi} \right]_0^{1/2} \\
&= \frac{- \sin(2 \pi t -  \pi)} {2 \pi} -\frac{-\sin(2 \pi t)}{2\pi}
 = - \frac{\sin(2 \pi t -  \pi)}{2\pi} + \frac{\sin(2 \pi t)}{2\pi} \\
&= \frac{\sin(2 \pi t)}{2\pi} + \frac{\sin(2 \pi t)}{2\pi}
 = \frac{\sin(2 \pi t)}{\pi}
\end{align*}

Comment: Why is it so hard to get an (impulse) response from anyone here?

Comment: What's your question? You just said: "I tried ..." Why do you think what you did is wrong?